# Simple ruby filter in Logstash

Tags: ruby, logstash, elastic-stack

I kept running into a wall trying to get a ruby file to work for a filter and I finally simplified my config file to simply this:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "event.cancel"
    }
}
```

But even with this simple example, running logstash.bat -t gives me the following:

> The given configuration is invalid. Reason: uninitialized constant LogStashCompilerLSCLGrammar::LogStash::Compiler::LSCL::AST::Hash::ConfigurationError

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get a ruby filter to work at all?  Same thing happening with fresh install of 6.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I should have gone further and simplified even more.  I still received the error even after removing then entire `ruby { }` section which meant my issue was elsewhere.  Sorry to waste viewing time.  I found my issue with another filters `add_field` not working correctly.  Lesson learned: Make one change at a time and test...